# In bash recursive script, how can I create folder and move files within sub-directory?

Tags: bash, file, recursion, move, subdirectory

I have a simple problem which I can probably do manually but want automated script because I have 820 folders!

There is one directory 'data' that has 820 folders: /data/001../data/820.

Within each folder I have identical file structure and file names. I want to create a new folder called 'thrash' and move two files called 'one.exe' and 'nine.dat' into thrash.

I want to do this recursively for all folders within my 'data' folder.

So create /data/001/thrash and then move one.exe and nine.dat to /data/001/thrash.
Then create /data/002/thrash and then move one.exe and nine.data to /data/002/thrash etc.

Is there a neat way for this? Please help.

Comment: Use the `find` command to iterate recursively and execute a script in each folder.

Comment: Your question says recursive, but it looks like you just have a single level of folders. Do you need to nest further down?

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the directories.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p data/*/thrash

for folder in data/*/; do
    mv "${folder}one.exe" "${folder}nine.exe" "${folder}thrash"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! This works on my Linux machine! Is there an equivalent of this for Windows?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't do windows.

Comment: @Barmar I have a similar need, but instead of naming "thrash inside the folder".  would like to create a new folder in a different location with the `name of the folder+today_date` from where I'm moving the files. Within that folder, would like to create sub-folders based on the file type I'm moving. For example, `folder_1/CSV_folder/all_csv_files` folder_1/excel_folder/all_excel_files` . Basically, trying to move only the .extension files I need from all the folders ( have about folder_1 .... folder_100). Have  you answered something similar ?

Comment: `name_of_folder_$(date '+%F')/folder_$i/CSV_folder/all_csv_files`

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for dir in rootdir/*
do
  if [[ -d ${dir} ]]; then
    (
    cd ${dir} || return
    mv one.exe newfolder/one.exe
    )
  fi
done
```

adapt this

Comment: `for dir in rootdir` doesn't get subdirectories. This just iterates over one directory.

Comment: I forgot glob star rootdir/*

Comment: You need to create `newfolder` before you can move into it.

Comment: yes,  it isn't a complete script just a snippet, I write below it, that it need adapt

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner (should be run in data directory):

```
for d in {001..820}; do mkdir $d/thrash; mv $d/{one.exe,nine.dat,thrash}; done
```